# Find relationship between values within finate range of integer domain

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

**Update:**

There are some misakes in the coefficient of `left` and `right`.
But still get similar result.

I understand the mathematica gives me the result in sort of detailed expression.
However I want the result simplified in the condition of `left == right && 0<=b<8 && 0<=d<4, NonNegativeIntergers`.

Assume `a<4 && c < 2` we have:

[image: table explain]

Apprently **As long as right == left, then d == b %4**.
So I want to get simplified `d = Mod[b, 4]`.
The condition `right == left` should already eliminate the assumption of `a` and `c`.

In the general case of `a`, `c` the conclusion still holds in the condition of that "As long as" above.

P.S.
I tried to use the following, still not get what I want.

```
Reduce[left == right && 0 <= b < 8 && 0 <= d < 4 && a<2 && c < 4, d,  NonNegativeIntegers]
```

---

A simple question of calculation coordinates of axis align tensor.

```
left = 8 a + b 
right = 4 c + d 
Reduce[left == right && 0<=b<8 && 0<=d<4,d,NonNegativeIntegers ]
```

Got

[image: result]

However I expect d = b % 4

```
  d = Mod[b, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
left = 4 a + b;
right = 8 c + d;

(sol = Solve[left == right && 0 <= b < 8 && 0 <= d < 4, d,
    PositiveIntegers]) // InputForm

(* {{d -> ConditionalExpression[1, 
    (C[1] >= 0 && Element[C[1], 
       Integers] && a == 
       2 + 2*C[1] && b == 1 && 
      c == 1 + C[1]) || 
     (C[1] >= 0 && Element[C[1], 
       Integers] && c == 
       1 + C[1] && a == 
       1 + 2*C[1] && b == 5)]}, 
 {d -> ConditionalExpression[2, 
    (C[1] >= 0 && Element[C[1], 
       Integers] && a == 
       2 + 2*C[1] && 
      c == 1 + C[1] && b == 2) || 
     (C[1] >= 0 && Element[C[1], 
       Integers] && c == 
       1 + C[1] && a == 
       1 + 2*C[1] && b == 6)]}, 
 {d -> ConditionalExpression[3, 
    (C[1] >= 0 && Element[C[1], 
       Integers] && a == 
       2 + 2*C[1] && 
      c == 1 + C[1] && b == 3) || 
     (C[1] >= 0 && Element[C[1], 
       Integers] && c == 
       1 + C[1] && a == 
       1 + 2*C[1] && b == 7)]}} *)
```

Checking whether `d == Mod[b, 4]`

```
(d == Mod[b, 4] /. sol //
   FullSimplify[#, Element[C[1], NonNegativeIntegers]] &) //
 InputForm

(* {ConditionalExpression[True, 
  c == 1 + C[1] && 
   ((a == 1 + 2*C[1] && b == 5) || 
    (a == 2 + 2*C[1] && b == 1))], 
 ConditionalExpression[True, 
  c == 1 + C[1] && 
   ((a == 1 + 2*C[1] && b == 6) || 
    (a == 2 + 2*C[1] && b == 2))], 
 ConditionalExpression[True, 
  c == 1 + C[1] && 
   ((a == 1 + 2*C[1] && b == 7) || 
    (a == 2 + 2*C[1] && b == 3))]} *)
```

`d == Mod[b, 4]`is only conditionally `True`; `a`, `b`, and `c` need to have appropriate values.

Comment: Hi I update the questions, and correct the mistake in the `left` and `right`